# fitting arrays on

Tags: tables, matrices

How can I get two matrices to fit side by side, centred on the page? Is there a way of automatically printing to 2 decimal places?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\begin{document}
%\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{align}
CI_{\text{lower} 5\%}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0.0286 &   0.4167 &   0.2353 &   0.0345 &   0.0286\\
    0.1296  &  0.0196 &   0.0196 &   0.4506 &   0.0164\\
    0.0962 &   0.0192 &   0.2564  &  0.0208 &   0.3217\\
    0.0472  &  0.1399&    0.1358 &   0.3708&    0.0465\\
    0.0383 &  0.0383&    0.1429 &   0.2308&    0.0383
\end{pmatrix}\quad&\quad CI_{\text{upper} 5\%}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0.0588&    0.5714  &  0.4195 &   0.2471&    0.0588\\
    0.3671&    0.2402  &  0.0921  &  0.7736 &   0.0236\\
    0.3454&    0.0270 &   0.3995 &   0.1332  &  0.4695\\
    0.1690&    0.2554 &   0.2421  &  0.5266 &   0.1334\\
    0.1000&    0.1000&    0.5714  &  0.7029 &   0.1000
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The matrices are too large. Even with `\tiny` an overfull `\hbox` message is generated with standard layout settings. Put them in *two* lines or use landscape format (package `lscape`/`pdflscape`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With dirty tricks, the cell contents of `pmatrix` can be caught and the number of digits can be reduced with the help of package `fp`/`fp-snap`. But your matrices are still *much too larger* for normal page layouts. Additionally `\tiny` is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fp-snap}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \newcolumntype{c}{>{\catchnum}l}
  \makeatletter
  \def\catchnum\ignorespaces#1\unskip{%
    \edef\x{\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
    \FPround\x\x{2}%
    \x
  }   
  \tiny
  \begin{align}
  CI_{\text{lower} 5\%}=\begin{pmatrix}
      0.0286 &   0.4167 &   0.2353 &   0.0345 &   0.0286 \unskip\\
      0.1296  &  0.0196 &   0.0196 &   0.4506 &   0.0164 \unskip\\
      0.0962 &   0.0192 &   0.2564  &  0.0208 &   0.3217 \unskip\\
      0.0472  &  0.1399&    0.1358 &   0.3708&    0.0465 \unskip\\
      0.0383 &  0.0383&    0.1429 &   0.2308&    0.0383 \unskip   
  \end{pmatrix}\quad&\quad CI_{\text{upper} 5\%}=\begin{pmatrix}
      0.0588&    0.5714  &  0.4195 &   0.2471&    0.0588 \unskip\\
      0.3671&    0.2402  &  0.0921  &  0.7736 &   0.0236 \unskip\\
      0.3454&    0.0270 &   0.3995 &   0.1332  &  0.4695 \unskip\\
      0.1690&    0.2554 &   0.2421  &  0.5266 &   0.1334 \unskip\\
      0.1000&    0.1000&    0.5714  &  0.7029 &   0.1000 \unskip  
  \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}  
\endgroup
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: tiny]

But I think the result is horrible. The matrices can easily be shown in two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{gather}
    \begin{aligned}
    CI_{\text{lower} 5\%} &=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.0286 &   0.4167 &   0.2353 &   0.0345 &   0.0286\\
        0.1296  &  0.0196 &   0.0196 &   0.4506 &   0.0164\\
        0.0962 &   0.0192 &   0.2564  &  0.0208 &   0.3217\\
        0.0472  &  0.1399&    0.1358 &   0.3708&    0.0465\\
        0.0383 &  0.0383&    0.1429 &   0.2308&    0.0383
    \end{pmatrix}\\CI_{\text{upper} 5\%} &=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.0588&    0.5714  &  0.4195 &   0.2471&    0.0588\\
        0.3671&    0.2402  &  0.0921  &  0.7736 &   0.0236\\
        0.3454&    0.0270 &   0.3995 &   0.1332  &  0.4695\\
        0.1690&    0.2554 &   0.2421  &  0.5266 &   0.1334\\
        0.1000&    0.1000&    0.5714  &  0.7029 &   0.1000
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{gather}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: two lines]

An alternative is switching to landscape orientation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{gather}
    CI_{\text{lower} 5\%} =\begin{pmatrix}
        0.0286 &   0.4167 &   0.2353 &   0.0345 &   0.0286\\
        0.1296  &  0.0196 &   0.0196 &   0.4506 &   0.0164\\
        0.0962 &   0.0192 &   0.2564  &  0.0208 &   0.3217\\
        0.0472  &  0.1399&    0.1358 &   0.3708&    0.0465\\
        0.0383 &  0.0383&    0.1429 &   0.2308&    0.0383
    \end{pmatrix}\quad\quad CI_{\text{upper} 5\%} =\begin{pmatrix}
        0.0588&    0.5714  &  0.4195 &   0.2471&    0.0588\\
        0.3671&    0.2402  &  0.0921  &  0.7736 &   0.0236\\
        0.3454&    0.0270 &   0.3995 &   0.1332  &  0.4695\\
        0.1690&    0.2554 &   0.2421  &  0.5266 &   0.1334\\
        0.1000&    0.1000&    0.5714  &  0.7029 &   0.1000
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{gather}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

> [image: landscape]

Comment: But actually how can I centre these arrays if they are on the same line? This is really the most important, I have to force them on some way or other.